# What is the best preposition in this sentence? "Since the 1960s, ——— the ascent of Noam Chomsky, the consensus has been that

Tags: prepositions, cloze-test

What is the best preposition for this sentence and why?

The full sentence is:

- Since the 1960s,  ——— the ascent of thinkers like Noam Chomsky, the consensus has been that linguistic differences don't really matter.

1- with
2- in
3- for

I'd really appreciate your answers.

Update:
I have checked some corpora for these phrases: “with the ascent of”, “in the ascent of”, and “by the ascent of”, and it seems that all of them are frequently used and the number of occurrences of each phrase does not give us a clear hint about one specifically correct or idiomatic phrase.

Look at these sentences, for example:

That rivalry, though, has been eclipsed in recent months by the ascent of Novak Djokovic. (The New York Times)

The three-part process by which the gross becomes the taken for granted has been on matchlessly grim view this past week in the ascent of Donald Trump. (The New Yorker)

And her worst political fears came true with the ascent of the Nazis. (The New York Times)

So I want to know what makes “with” the best preposition for the original sentence.

Comment: As with many test questions posted here, this doesn't seem particularly grammatical. There should probably be "of" between "ascent" and "thinkers". But we're not here to do your homework, so say what answer you consider right and what problem you are having.

Comment: Since the 1960s, with the ascent of thinkers like Noam Chomsky, the consensus among grammarians has been that linguistic differences don't really matter.

Comment: You are right. 
I edited the first question to make myself clearer.

Comment: I find think that "Since the ascent of thinkers like Noam Chomsky in the in 1960s, ..." might be a slightly smoother wording.

Comment: You may not be familiar with our sister site “English Language Learners” which I suggest may be a more suitable place to ask questions about use of prepositions in English.

Comment: This is a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I want to know what makes “with” the best preposition for the original sentence.

With has the sense of **accompanied by** - "Since the 1960s, [which were] **accompanied by** the ascent of thinkers like Noam Chomsky, ..."

e.g. He went to the park **with** John.